# where is the data stored when using the Entity.Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a data initialize class to store some data at the beginning.
I would like to view this data now to see how it looks like.
Can it be done somehow? What's this data stored as by the way, is it mssql?

```
public class AccountsInitializer : 
    DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Base.Models.AccountRepository>
{
    protected override void Seed(Models.AccountRepository context)
    {
         context.Accounts.Add(admin);
         ...
         base.Seed();
    }
}
```

**app.config file**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Accounts" 
         connectionString="data source=yoaynzmjvq.database.windows.net;
         Initial Catalog=accounts;
         User ID= ...;
         Password=...;
         Encrypt=true;
         Trusted_Connection=false;
         MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: How did you configure EF? It works with multiple database types.

Comment: @jrummell I did not configure it at all. I took over a project from somebody. But I found the configuration details. I added it to my question

Answer (score 0):

According to your connection string, it's an MS SQL (SqlClient) database called `accounts` (Initial Catalog) on a server called `yoaynzmjvq.database.windows.net` (Data Source).

Comment: i'm all new to the .NET world. Can you tell me how I can access the mssql? I only worked with mysql before in which simply used the command line or phpmyadmin

Comment: That server looks like it's a SQL Azure instance.

Comment: You can use SSMS. See [Use SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx)

Comment: there's seems no straight forward way to download it. And it seems to be different version of it. I think I need to download the 2008 version of the management which I found here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593 but it seems to be installation for SQL server 2008 only, plus it complains about compatibility issue when I try. Do you happen to know where the actual program is for download?

Comment: That's the correct download link for the free Express version. The commercial version is included with the installer for SQL Server.